# Drop-down menu and radio button can't be selected

Tags: html, css

When I click on the radio button and the drop-down arrow, they won't work. I click on them and nothing happens. I suppose something is hidden but i cannot tell.

Can someone help me?

Here's the link to my project: https://codepen.io/Ozubergs/pen/VdKRmd?editors=1100

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `position: relative` in wrong way. That is creating the problem. I have commented it. And add   `vertical-align: top;` for labels and submit button.

```css
.header {
  margin: 2%;
}

#survey-form {
  background: #722f2d;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.labels {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.inputs {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.fields {
  width: 210px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#submit {
    vertical-align: top;
}
/* .radio-buttons {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 55px;
  display: block;
}

.radio {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  right: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.checkboxes{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 145px;
}

.checkbox{
  position: relative;
  top: 164px;
  right: 30px;
} 

.lbl {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 3px;
}

textarea {
  margin-top: 4%;
}

#submit {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 91px;
  margin: 10px;
}*/
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="text-center" id="title">Survey</h1>
    <p class="text-center" id="description">Let us know how to improve this survey</p>
  </div>
  <form id="survey-form">
    <div class="input-name">
      <div class="labels">
        <label for="name" id="name-label">* Name:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="inputs">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter full name" id="name" class="fields">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-email">
      <div class="labels">
        <label for="email" id="email-label">* Email:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="inputs">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email" id="email" class="fields">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-age">
      <div class="labels">
        <label for="number" id="number-label">* Age:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="inputs">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Age" id="number" class="fields">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="labels">
      <label>What are you?</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
      <select id="dropdown">
        <option>Student</option>
        <option>Full time employee</option>
        <option>Part time employee</option>
        <option>Self-learner</option>
        <option>Prefer not to say</option>
        <option>Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-buttons">
      <div class="labels">
        <label>Do you like this survey?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="inputs">
        <ul style="list-style:none">
          <li class="radio"><input type="radio" id="male" value="1"><label for="male" class="lbl">Yes</label></li>
          <li class="radio"><input type="radio" id="female" value="2"><label for="female" class="lbl">No</label></li>
          <li class="radio"><input type="radio" id="other" value="3"><label for="other" class="lbl">Meh</label></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkboxes">
      <div class="labels">
        <label>How should I improve?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="inputs">
        <ul style="list-style:none">
          <li class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="add"><label for="add" class="lbl">Add more detail</label></li>
          <li class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="2" id="clean"><label for="clean" class="lbl">Clean it up</label></li>
          <li class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="3" id="design"><label for="design" class="lbl">Design it better</label></li>
          <li class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="4" id="create"><label for="create" class="lbl">Someone else should create the survey</label></li>
          <li class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="5" id="confidence"><label for="confidence" class="lbl">Have confidence</label></li>
          <li class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="6" id="more"><label for="more" class="lbl">Add more buttons</label></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-box text-center">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="30" placeholder="Enter your comments here..."></textarea>
      <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening is due to your CSS positioning technique. Since you are pushing everything around with relative positioning you have elements that are covering your drop down as well as your radio buttons which is why they aren't working. Your design can be achieved without relative positioning.